# Why is the base() constructor not necessary?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have a class structure like

```
abstract class Animal {
  public Animal(){
    //init stuff..
  }
}

class Cat : Animal {
  public Cat(bool is_keyboard) : base() //NOTE here
  {
    //other init stuff
  }
}
```

Now then, look at the noted line. If you remove `: base()` then it will compile without an error.

Why is this? Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an implicit `: base()` if you don't add anything else (any `: base(...)` or `: this(...)`). To force it to be explicit, add a parameter to the base-constructor(s). Then it can't be implicit.

For example:

```
public Animal(string name) {...}
```

Comment: Cool, you learn something everyday... I've always explicitly put base(), probably will continue to do so because how many developers realise there is an implicit call to it?

Comment: Also, I found Skeet's nifty article that told me all about it: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html

Comment: @slugster, I didn't realize it... so yea.

Answer (score 1):

[17.10.4 Default Constructors](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/17.10.4.htm):

> If a class contains no instance
>   constructor declarations, a default
>   instance constructor is automatically
>   provided. 2 That default constructor
>   simply invokes the parameterless
>   constructor of the direct base class.
>   3 If the direct base class does not
>   have an accessible parameterless
>   instance constructor, a compile-time
>   error occurs. 4 If the class is
>   abstract then the declared
>   accessibility for the default
>   constructor is protected. 5 Otherwise,
>   the declared accessibility for the
>   default constructor is public

Comment: While true, that is the wrong section for what happens when ` : base()` is removed. That section tells what happens if the entire constructor is removed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this?

This [article](http://dotnetperls.com/base-constructor) explains it.

> Is there a way to disable this
>   behavior?

Nope. I'm sorry (but ... See mark answer for a workaround : )