# Is the usage of base() meaningful?

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, radix

When reading the code of my company,
I found there are quite some of below code

```
class Child:Parent
{
    public Child():base()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

My question is whether the usage of `:base()` is meaningful?
Before calling `Child()`, the `base()` will be automatically called, am I right?
I mean the constructor without parameters.

Comment: @raymelfrancisco: Please do not add language names in title. They are not required due to presence of tags. I have **approved and improved** your edit only because of other changes that you had made :)

Comment: Similiar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2556427/4895040

Comment: here is useless but if you want to call another constructor. for example the constructor that takes two arguments then `base` is usefull. ex: `base(name, age)`

Comment: Personally I find it easier to follow the program flow if it's explicitly called, but as others have said, in this case it's not needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right! The :base() is not necessary in that case, but it is necessary if your parent class does not have parameterless constructors.

Following the MSDN Documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115(v=vs.90).aspx

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called
>   explicitly by using the base keyword, the default constructor, if
>   there is one, is called implicitly.
>   This means that the following constructor declarations are effectively the same:

```
public Manager(int initialdata)
{
    //Add further instructions here.
}

public Manager(int initialdata)
    : base()
{
    //Add further instructions here.
}
```

> If a base class does not offer a default constructor, the derived
>   class must make an explicit call to a base constructor by using base.

Hope it helps!